# PAM Module works fine on i386 but fails on x64 when used in vsftpd

Tags: linux, ftp, pam, vsftpd

We have a custom PAM module that works fine on our i386 development machines but when we try and use it in production on our x64 production servers with vsftpd it fails. The PAM module has been recompiled for x64.

auth.log:

```
Nov 12 18:29:06 [removed] vsftpd: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_databowl.so): libcrypt.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
```

(n.b We have a huge amount of free memory)

syslog:

```
Nov 12 18:29:06 [removed]  kernel: [13831373.215161] vsftpd[6955]: segfault at 968 ip 00007fc50dabc8f0 sp 00007fff755e1a30 error 4 in libpthread-2.15.so[7fc50dab6000+18000]
```

However, using the `pamtester` tool it works fine:

```
[removed]:~/pamtester-0.1.2/src$ ./pamtester vsftpd.databowl <removed> authenticate
Password: 
pamtester: successfully authenticated
```

We are unsure what is causing this error. Does anyone know how to solve this or have any suggestions on how we could further debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after I posted this I managed to solve it. It turns out vsftpd limits the amount of virtual memory available using `setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, limit)` I guess this was fine on 32bit but it was exhausting this on 64bit. I've not bothered to find an exact limit where this problem occurs but recompiling vsftpd and altering `VSFTP_AS_LIMIT` in vsftpd's `defs.h` to triple the limit has removed the problem and the PAM module is working great.